# Serving previous javascript static files in nginx deployment

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, nginx, continuous-integration, cicd

I've react app baked in nginx container running in my Kubernetes cluster.
Each time I merge a pull request my CI/CD process creates a new container image with the static files and replace the targetRevision in my deployment (I'm using ArgoCD).
My deployment is running with 2 replicas and default rollingUpdate strategy (25% maxSurge and 25% maxUnavailable).

I notice that during the time of the deployment I'm getting 1-3 404 errors when serving the previous version of static files (e.g., `GET /static/js/635.2a6f7fb8.js.map HTTP/1.1`)

If I understand correctly, these error comes from client request previous static files versions, so I'm exploring my options to solve this.
One idea is to configure nginx fallback to static files in s3/efs.
This means, my CI process will copy (amend) new static files to a place (s3) where it stores all previous versions - I'm not fan of this option since it complicate my CI.

I really like the fact that my static files are baked in the container image because it's very fast serving and make my CI clean and simple.

Can you please suggest another idea?

UPDATE -
Most of the mentioned 404 errors are related to LogRocket-AssetCacher and not real users, but still something I want to fix

Answer (score 0):

if your index.html is not cached, then as soon as the new container is up with latest assets, it should be able to serve new static file versions which is requested by new index.html.

so any new page refresh should be able to load the required assets.

404 can only come if your replica is >2 , and then user is able to load old index.html and then it tries to load old static assets from new container.

if you have >2 container and you want to avoid these, then don't go for rolling deployment. instead go for blue green.